# How to validate a variable using Generic Type

Tags: c#

I have the following to validate a type:

```
Boolean valid = Int32.TryParse(value, out result);
```

How can use TryParse for a Generic? For example:

```
public Boolean Validate<T>(Object value) {
  // Get TryParse of T type and check if value is of that type.
}
```

How can I validate value to check if it is of type T?

Comment: If you don't know the actual type until runtime (which tends to be when such questions arise), how will you actually consume this information sanely?

Comment: I think you mean for your value parameter to be of type string

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get the proper overload of `TryParse` and the invoke it:

```
public static bool Validate<T>(string value)
{
   var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static;
   var method = typeof(T).GetMethod(
            "TryParse",
            flags,
            null,
            new[] { typeof(string), typeof(T).MakeByRefType() },
            null);
    if (method != null)
    {
         T result = default(T);
         return (bool)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { value, result });
    }
    else
    {
        // there is no appropriate TryParse method on T so the type is not supported
    }
}
```

The usage would be like the following:

```
bool isValid = Validate<double>("12.34");
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all data types implement a parse or tryparse method. However, many types have an associated TypeConverter that you could use to attempt converting from a string.

```
public Boolean Validate<T>(string value) 
{
     var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
     return converter != null ? converter.IsValid(value) : false;
}
```

Comment: Should I not check if the converter exists? You said that many types have ... not all.

Comment: I added a check if the converter exists. This technique should be able to convert more types from string than looking for a Parse method. Another technique is to use the System.Convert class, but again, that won't cover as many types.